# Unable to access network path using WMI managementClass.InvokeMethod

Tags: c#, network-programming, wmi, remote-desktop

I have been trying to launch text pad installation from network path to a remote machine using `WMI managementclass.InvokeMethod`.
However several attempts have failed with

> error code 1602

So I created a batch file containing script to launch installation  executable from network path in a remote machine, and tried to invoke it with `managementclass.InvokeMethod`.
However, even this didn't work.

I tried the same by changing the executable from network path to remote machine `C:\path`.
And it worked!!!

But I want to launch the installation executable from a network path.

I would be grateful if somebody would help me.

Comment: does the user which you are using to connect to the remote machine have access to the shared resource??

Comment: Yes NicoRiff , user does have access to shared resource from remote machine. In fact I was able to successfully run batch file operation with shared path if launch it from remote machine.